# Lie group representation, exponential, and $\theta$-periodicty

Tags: representation-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

> SU(2)

I know we can view the group element in the SU(2) Lie group as
$$ g = \exp\left(\theta\sum_{k=1}^{3} i t_k \frac{\sigma_k}{2}\right)  $$
where $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ forms a unit vector [effectively pointing in some direction on a unit 2-sphere $S^2$], and $\sigma_k$ are Pauli matrices:
\begin{align}
  \sigma_1 = \sigma_x &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0&1\\
      1&0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
  \sigma_2 = \sigma_y &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0&-i\\
      i&0
    \end{pmatrix} \\
  \sigma_3 = \sigma_z &=
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0\\
      0&-1
    \end{pmatrix} \,.
\end{align}
Notice that any group element on $SU(2)$ can be parametrized by some $\theta$ and $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$. Also $\theta$ has a periodicity $[0,4 \pi)$, instead of $2 \pi$.
Notice that in this case we also have
$$ g = \exp\left(\theta\sum_{k=1}^{3} i t_k \frac{\sigma_k}{2}\right)  
=\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})+i \sum_{k=1}^{3}  t_k \sigma_k\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$$

> question 1: SU(3)

(1) Is this true that all $SU(3)$ group elements can be written as:
$$ g = \exp\left(\theta\sum_{k=1}^{8} i t_k \frac{\lambda_k}{2}\right)=\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})+i \sum_{k=1}^{8}  t_k \lambda_k\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})  $$
where $\lambda_k$ are [Gell-Mann_matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices)? And does the second equality still hold? Here Tr$(\lambda_k^2)=2.$
**Also $\theta$ has a periodicity $[0,4 \pi)$?**

> question 2: SU(n), for $n=4, ...$

(2) Is this true that all $SU(4)$ group elements can be written as:
$$ g = \exp\left(\theta\sum_{k=1}^{4^2-1} i t_k \frac{\lambda_k}{2}\right)=\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})+i \sum_{k=1}^{4^2-1}  t_k \lambda_k\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})  $$
where $\lambda_k$ are [generalized rank-4 Gell-Mann_matrices in eq.(3)](http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv10i28p9.pdf)? And does the second equality still hold? Here Tr$(\lambda_k^2)=2.$
**Also $\theta$ has a periodicity $[0,4 \pi)$?**

(3) How to determine the Right Hand side equation and **$\theta$  periodicity?**

Comment: I don't think so. For one thing, these matrices (times $i$) do not square to $-I$, although each such squared matrices act as $-I$ on a 2D subspace and $0$ on the complement. That could be fixed with some multiple of $I$ in the formula though. The bigger issue is that the very last such matrix does not anticommute with the other ones.

Comment: You are confusing matrices with numbers. In particular, your sentence "Notice that in this case we also have..." is plain wrong.

Comment: @ Moishe Cohen, it is not wrong at least for SU(2) case, there is an implicit identity matrix in the cos$(\theta/2)$ term. I am rewriting the rank 2 matrice. It is standard for SU(2) case

Answer (score 4):

There are two key facts that contribute the SU(2) formula for Pauli matrices:

- Distinct Pauli matrices *anticommute*
- Times them by $i$ to get square roots of $-I$

The importance can be seen by squaring a "vector" with them as basis:

$$ (it_1\sigma_1+it_2\sigma_2+it_3\sigma_3)^2=-(t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2) $$

(working this algebra out is instructive). This means $t:=it_1\sigma_1+it_2\sigma_2+it_3\sigma_3$ is a square root of $-I$ when $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ is a unit vector, and thus by the usual proof of de Moivre's formula,

$$ \exp(\theta t)=\cos(\theta)I+\sin(\theta)t. $$

However the Gell-Mann matrices are not as nice. First notice

$$ (i\lambda_1)^2=(i\lambda_2)^2=\mathrm{diag}(-1,-1,0) \\ (i\lambda_4)^2=(i\lambda_5)^2=\mathrm{diag}(-1,0,-1) \\ (i\lambda_6)^2=(i\lambda_7)^2=\mathrm{diag}(0,-1,-1) $$

so these are not quite square roots of $-I$, although that could potentially be fixed in a tentative exponential formula since their sum *is* a multiple of $-I$. But then the symmetry gets broken:

$$ (i\lambda_3)^2 = \mathrm{diag}(-1,-1,0) \\ (i\lambda_8)^2=\mathrm{diag}(-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3},-\frac{4}{3}). $$

Thus, in particular,

$$\exp(\theta i\lambda_8)\ne \cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta)\lambda_8.$$

Moreover, one can verify some of the pairs of Gell-Mann matrices do not anticommute.

Comment: anon thanks for your efforts! ;D

Comment: so to be accepted as an answer, you should answer my question. What is the theta periodicity? Do we span the full Lie group SU(3) by my construction?

Comment: @ anon. I am still not fully happy about my question. thanks

Comment: @annieheart Notice $i$ times the Gell-Mann matrices form a basis for the lie algebra ${\frak su}(n)$, and the exponential map $\exp:{\frak su}(n)\to SU(n)$ is onto since $SU(n)$ is compact. Your exponential formula will almost never be periodic in $\theta$, though. When the element $g$ of ${\frak su}(n)$ happens to satisfy $g^2=-kI$ (where $k>0$) then $\exp(\theta g)$ will have period $2\pi/\sqrt{k}$. Writing out the conditions $g^2=-kI$ with the GM basis will I expect produce some complicated system of equations.

Comment: @ anon , thanks. Then how do we obtain the full continuous parametrization of SU(n)? If you suggest what I wrote does not give the full parametrization of SU(n)?

Comment: Here is another one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728576, related to U(n=3). Thanks anon!

Comment: @annieheart I never said what you wrote doesn't give a full parametrization. In fact, I said the exponential map is indeed onto. What I also said was that your formulas for $\exp(\theta g)$ (in terms of $\cos$s and $\sin$s) generally don't hold, and generally $\exp(\theta g)$ isn't periodic in $\theta$.

Comment: I think you meant in your post $\exp(\theta i\lambda_8)\ne \cos(\theta)+i \sin(\theta)\lambda_8$?

Comment: But it looks to me that this paper discussed the exponential form of the $SU(n)$ Lie group element, what may be the reason for that? https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9710024

Comment: See also: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/22/23/002/pdf - A disentanglement relation for SU(3) coherent states
K Raghunathan, M Seetharaman and S S Vasan

Comment: See also Coherent States For SU(3) - Manu Mathur, Diptiman Sen - https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0012099

Comment: @wonderich I never said the exponential parametrization wasn't used by people or worthy of study or had formulas out there somehwere. I just said OP's attempted generalization of the SU(2) exponential formula to SU(3) was false.

Answer (score 3):

At least for SU(3), the exponential of arbitrary Lie-algebra elements in the fundamental representation is a bit more complicated, and, as a consequence of the Cayley-Hamilton theory, it also has a term *bilinear* in the Lie algebra elements, unlike the simple SU(2) expression you may be hankering for. See [Curtright & Zachos 2015](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0034-4877(15)30040-9), and [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.00868.pdf).

Specifically, the generic  SU(3) group element generated by a traceless 3×3 Hermitian matrix  *H*, normalized as  tr*H*<sup>2</sup> = 2, can be expressed as a second order  matrix polynomial in  *H*,
$$\begin{align}
  \exp(i\theta H) ={}
          &\left[-\frac{1}{3} I\sin\left(\varphi + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right) \sin\left(\varphi - \frac{2\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}~H\sin(\varphi) - \frac{1}{4}~H^2\right]
           \frac{\exp\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}~i\theta\sin(\varphi)\right)}
                {\cos\left(\varphi + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right) \cos\left(\varphi - \frac{2\pi}{3}\right)} \\[4pt]
    {}+{} &\left[-\frac{1}{3}~I\sin(\varphi) \sin\left(\varphi - \frac{2\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}~H\sin\left(\varphi + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{1}{4}~H^{2}\right]
           \frac{\exp\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}~i\theta \sin\left(\varphi + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right)}
                {\cos(\varphi) \cos\left(\varphi - \frac{2\pi}{3}\right)} \\[4pt]
    {}+{} &\left[-\frac{1}{3}~I\sin(\varphi) \sin\left(\varphi + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}~H \sin\left(\varphi - \frac{2\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{1}{4}~H^2\right]
           \frac{\exp\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}~i\theta \sin\left(\varphi - \frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right)}
                {\cos(\varphi)\cos\left(\varphi + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right)}
\end{align} $$
where
 $$\varphi \equiv \frac{1}{3}\left[\arccos\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\det H\right) - \frac{\pi}{2}\right]. $$

Comment: Thanks! This helps! I am glad to see this nice answer! +1

Comment: Do you only need a single $H$? or do you have $H$ represents a proper sum of within the 8 of SU(3) Lie algebra generators?

Comment: Yes, *any* sum of Gell-Mann matrices with suitable coefficients so the trace condition chosen is satisfied  will do. This is the *most* general expression.  Satisfy yourself it works for the most general diagonal combination of $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_8$ so normalized, etc... The proof is straightforward, but not as trivial as for SU(2)...